# Flask session not saving value/persisting across requests

Tags: session, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-session

```
bp = Blueprint('store', __name__)

@bp.route('/cart/<product_id>')
def add_to_cart(product_id):
    print(session)
    if "order_id" in session:
        print(session["order_id"])
        order = Order.query.get(session["order_id"])
        
        # add products to order object ...

    else:
        order = Order()
        db.session.add(order)
        db.session.commit()
        session["order_id"] = order.order_id
        session.modified = True

    return redirect(url_for('store.products'))
```

```
@bp.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def products():
    print(session)
```

When a user adds to cart the first time, I create a new order and save that order's order_id (an integer) in the session to add products to the order.
Then when they add to cart, I can query the Order and add products to it.

However, the session keeps resetting to an empty dictionary after the request to redirect to store.products page.
I'm not sure how to implement the session so that it persists across all requests and use it to keep track of the order_id.

My order table is defined as:

```
class Order(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Orders'
    order_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    products = db.relationship('Product', secondary=cart, back_populates='orders')

    customer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Customers.customer_id'))
    customer = db.relationship('Customer', back_populates='orders')

    quantities = db.relationship('Quantity')

    message = db.Column(db.Text)
```

Comment: Can you provide us with the `order` table? Make sure you also have a `SECRET_KEY`

Comment: Could this be an issue with your secret key?

Comment: I have set the secret key in my config file as SECRET_KEY = 'examplekeystring'

Comment: Also edited question to include order table